# How to understand the difference between the two online video: RTSP and HTTP?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I know the RTSP and HTTP two online video is support by android. But how to understand the difference between RTSP and HTTP. I want to know how to work when play the online video with RTSP or HTTP, and what is the difference between them.Thank you!

Comment: Check out the definitions of those standards: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

Answer (score 12, accepted):

RTSP stands for `Real Time Streaming Protocol`. One of the main uses for RTSP is to receive streaming video (e.g video on demand). A client establishes a connection with a media server and obtains data from the server and displays it.

HTTP, on the other hand, is a stateless protocol. HTTP provides a mechanism to download a media file over the internet. It would not be wrong to think of accessing media over HTTP as accessing a file over a network and playing it.

Comment: You could find another good explanation from this article: http://www.onlinevideo.net/2011/05/streaming-vs-progressive-download-vs-adaptive-streaming/

Answer (score 0):

I found this resource: [Streaming vs. progressive download: Understanding the difference](http://blog.mydeo.com/2009/01/12/streaming-vs-progressive-download-understanding-the-difference/)

Comment: The link is broken. I guess you are referring to http://blog.mydeo.com/2009/01/12/streaming-vs-progressive-download-understanding-the-difference/