# VLCJ stream video start time

Tags: java, networking, stream, vlcj

Im trying to stream a video from a certain minute with vlcj

What I've got and that works fine

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("VLC_PLUGIN_PATH", "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\plugins");
    File vlcInstallPath = new File("C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
    NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(
            RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), vlcInstallPath.getAbsolutePath());
    Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
    LibXUtil.initialise();

    String[] media = {"C:\\clips\\clip.mp4"};

    String options = ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=100,venc=x264{profile=baseline},fps=10,width=1920,height=1080,acodec=mp3,ab=24,channels=1,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=:8080/";
    MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory(media);
    HeadlessMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newHeadlessMediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.playMedia(media[0], options);
    Thread.currentThread().join();
}
```

But it always starts from the beginning,
when i start the stream using VLC Media Player.

What i expected was that the time of the stream keeps progressing and everytime i join the stream i jump to this time, but that didn't happen.
Is there any way to achieve that?

If not, is it possible to start the stream at a certain minute?

I've tried
`mediaPlayer.setTime(100);`
but it has no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got my mistake

[How to understand the difference between the two online video: RTSP and HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742010/how-to-understand-the-difference-between-the-two-online-video-rtsp-and-http)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("VLC_PLUGIN_PATH", "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\plugins");
    File vlcInstallPath = new File("C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
    NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(
            RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), vlcInstallPath.getAbsolutePath());
    Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
    LibXUtil.initialise();

    String[] media = {"C:\\clips\\clip.mp4"};

    //String options = ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=100,venc=x264{profile=baseline},fps=10,width=1920,height=1080,acodec=mp3,ab=24,channels=1,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=:8090/";
    String options = formatRtspStream("127.0.0.1",8080, "demo");//":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=100,venc=x264{profile=baseline},fps=10,width=1920,height=1080,acodec=mp3,ab=24,channels=1,samplerate=44100}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8090/}";
    MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory(media);
    HeadlessMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newHeadlessMediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.playMedia(media[0],
            options,
            ":no-sout-rtp-sap",
            ":no-sout-standard-sap",
            ":sout-all",
            ":sout-keep"
    );
    Thread.currentThread().join();
}

private static String formatRtspStream(String serverAddress, int serverPort, String id) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(60);
    sb.append(":sout=#rtp{sdp=rtsp://@");
    sb.append(serverAddress);
    sb.append(':');
    sb.append(serverPort);
    sb.append('/');
    sb.append(id);
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/blob/master/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/streaming/StreamRtsp.java

Comment: how did you call this i mean in your localhost ?